# Dynamically merge column name and values of a dataframe using lapply or apply or mapply functions

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have a `foo_dataframe` (see below) that I want to convert to transaction data:

```
foo_dataframe <- data.frame(replicate(50,1:4))
foo_dataframe 
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9...................X50
#1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
#3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
#4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

The transaction data I am expecting is below (i.e. the transaction data must be a concatenation of column name and each value of the dataframe):

```
#   X1    X2    X3    X4 ................X50
#1 X1 1  X2 1  X3 1  X4 1               X50 1 
#2 X1 2  X2 2  X3 2  X4 2               X50 2
#3 X1 3  X2 3  X3 3  X4 3               X50 3 
#4 X1 4  X2 4  X3 4  X4 4               X50 4
```

I can concatenate each column and its values with this code:

```
m <- paste(colnames(foo_dataframe)[1], foo_dataframe[[1]], "")
n <- paste(colnames(foo_dataframe)[2], foo_dataframe[[2]], "")
o <- paste(colnames(foo_dataframe)[3], foo_dataframe[[3]], "")
p <- paste(colnames(foo_dataframe)[4], foo_dataframe[[4]], "")
```

And later join them using `data.frame(m,n,o,p)` to produce:

```
#   X1    X2    X3    X4
#1 X1 1  X2 1  X3 1  X4 1 
#2 X1 2  X2 2  X3 2  X4 2 
#3 X1 3  X2 3  X3 3  X4 3 
#4 X1 4  X2 4  X3 4  X4 4
```

To save time, I think this can be done dynamically using apply functions because I have many columns to be done. However, when I tried apply function, with the code below:

```
c <- 1:length(length(colnames(foo_dataframe)))
t <- foo_dataframe
transactionData <- function(t, c){ # t = dataframe; c = column no.
  paste(colnames(t)[c], t[[c]], "")
}
foo_transactionData <- lapply(t, transactionData, c)
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in t[[c]] : attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

I have toiled stackoverflow to seek for solution but have not found any. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` :

```
foo_dataframe[] <- Map(paste, names(foo_dataframe), foo_dataframe)

foo_dataframe[, 1:4]

#    X1   X2   X3   X4
#1 X1 1 X2 1 X3 1 X4 1
#2 X1 2 X2 2 X3 2 X4 2
#3 X1 3 X2 3 X3 3 X4 3
#4 X1 4 X2 4 X3 4 X4 4
```

Using `lapply`, we can loop over the index of columns or their names

```
foo_dataframe[] <- lapply(names(foo_dataframe), function(x) 
                   paste(x, foo_dataframe[[x]]))
```

---

The equivalent options using `purrr` are :

```
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(foo_dataframe, ~paste(.y, .x))
map2_dfc(foo_dataframe, names(foo_dataframe), ~paste(.y, .x))
map_dfc(names(foo_dataframe), ~paste(.x, foo_dataframe[[.x]]))
```

---

**EDIT**

To avoid `NA` values from pasting we can do :

```
foo_dataframe[] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(y), "",paste(x, y)), 
                       names(foo_dataframe), foo_dataframe)
```

Comment: Thanks @ronak-shah. In a situation where there is `NA`, concatenating column name (e.g. X4) with a missing value, it will lead to `X4 NA`. Is there a way to set a condition to exclude `NA` (i.e. exclude concatenating column name with missing values)? Cheers.

Comment: @William Updated the answer this will print blaknk values when `NA` are present. You can check now

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. Blank values are only printed in columns that previously had `NA` throughout. Blank values are not printed in columns that has mixture of real values and NA. What was printed s still `X4 NA`are not blank values.

Comment: @William My bad I should have used `ifelse`. See updated answer if it works for your case.